# Manipulacao de arquivos TXT com MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo MVC, vejam abaixo:

RegistroRep.text

000185000|3|13072016|2357|12942973988 
000185001|3|14072016|0000|12739666685 
000185002|3|14072016|0800|12519046076 
000185003|3|14072016|0800|13303022983 
000185004|3|14072016|0800|16140197229 
000185005|3|14072016|0800|13136849980 
000185006|3|14072016|0801|11988133208

```
namespace WebAbrirArquivo.Models
{
    public class AbrirArquivo
    {
        public string MeuPis { get; set; }
    }
}
//---------------
namespace WebAbrirArquivo.Controllers
{
    public class AbrirArquivoController : Controller
    {
        public string Conteudo { get; private set; }
        public string StrLinha { get; private set; }
        public string Nsr { get; private set; }
        public string Dtop { get; private set; }
        public string HoraOp { get; private set; }
        public string NPis { get; private set; }

        // GET: AbrirArquivo
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            IList<string> linesArq = new List<string>();
            IList<String> BuscaQuadro = new List<String>();
            var outputFile = System.IO.File.CreateText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Uploads/OutputFile.txt"));
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);                  
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FileName))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                           StrLinha = reader.ReadLine();
                            Nsr = StrLinha.Substring(0, 9);
                            HoraOp = StrLinha.Substring(21, 4);
                            NPis = StrLinha.Substring(26, 11);
                            var DtOpC = StrLinha.Substring(12, 2) + "/" + StrLinha.Substring(14, 2) + "/" + StrLinha.Substring(16, 4) +
                            " " + StrLinha.Substring(21, 2) + ":" + StrLinha.Substring(23, 2) + ":" + 0 + 0;
                            linesArq.Add(Nsr + " " + NPis + " " + DtOpC + "\r\n");
                            outputFile.WriteLine(Nsr + " " + NPis + " " + DtOpC);                           
                        }
                    }
                    //  IEnumerable<string> GUARDACOL = linesArq.Where(Nsr => Nsr.Contains("12519046076")); // Valor passado diretamente funciona OK
                      IEnumerable<string> GUARDACOL = linesArq.Where(Nsr => Nsr.Contains(AbrirArquivo.MeuPis)); // Valor da View ERRO:
                    foreach (string NSR in GUARDACOL)
                    {
                        BuscaQuadro.Add(NSR);
                    }

                    // create new txt file
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.linesArq = BuscaQuadro;
            // return RedirectToAction("Upload");
            //if (files.Count() > 0) Console.WriteLine(files.Count()); // display 1
            //if (files.Any()) Console.WriteLine(files.Any()); // display true
            // if (files.First() == null) Console.WriteLine("first null"); // display "first null"
            return View();
        }


        // GET: OpenUpload
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
//------------
@model WebAbrirArquivo.Models.AbrirArquivo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Localizar Arquivo</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "AbrirArquivo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MeuPis, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeuPis, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MeuPis)
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p> <input name="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/methods_pt.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

//--------------------
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<h2>Arquivo Uploaded</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (string linesArq in ViewBag.linesArq)
    {
        <li>
            @linesArq
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

> ERRO: Uma referência de objeto é nescessaria para o campo "        IEnumerable GUARDACOL = linesArq.Where(Nsr => Nsr.Contains(AbrirArquivo.MeuPis));".

Comment: você não esta recebendo sua model (   AbrirArquivo ) , por isso esta nula.

Comment: O erro está ocorrendo por que a instância de AbrirArquivo é nula.
Em momento nenhum vejo em seu código a criação do objeto, muito mesmo setando a propriedade MeuPis.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, deu tudo certo, mas, ainda peco nos fundamentos.